# How to update a YML file with | seperator

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a .yml file that looks like this.

```
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hey
    - hello
    - hi
    - hello there
```

Now I want to update this file to add a new intent and example from python. But since the file has a | whenever I update it, the alignment of the file gets messed up.

Like so

```
with open('nlu.yml', 'r') as yamlfile:
    cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
    cur_yaml['nlu'].append({ 'intent': 'name', 'examples': ['first', 'second']})

with open('nlu.yml', 'w') as yamlfile:
     yaml.safe_dump(cur_yaml, yamlfile)
```

Comment: can't you just treat it like a txt file and append whatever you want? ensuring you keep the right indentation of course..or is this a much larger file where that would get tricky

Comment: @DerekEden it's not a big file at all but I'm thinking wouldn't it be complex to bring the right indentation, | etc if we treat it as a txt and then save it as a yml. or maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

`|` is *not* a separator. It is the header of a block scalar, meaning the value of `examples` is a scalar with the content `"- hey\n- hello\n- hi\n- hello there\n"`. To append another sequence item with the same semantic structure, you'll need to do

```py
with open('nlu.yml', 'r') as yamlfile:
    cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
    cur_yaml['nlu'].append({ 'intent': 'name', 'examples': "- first\n- second\n"})
```

Complete working example:

```py
import yaml, sys

input = """
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hey
    - hello
    - hi
    - hello there
"""

cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(input)
cur_yaml['nlu'].append({ 'intent': 'name', 'examples': "- first\n- second"})

yaml.safe_dump(cur_yaml, sys.stdout)
```

This outputs

```yaml
nlu:
- examples: '- hey

    - hello

    - hi

    - hello there

    '
  intent: greet
- examples: '- first

    - second

    '
  intent: name
```

Now while this output has the correct YAML semantic, you may dislike the way it's formatted. For an in-depth explanation of why this is happening, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964).

The takeaway from the answer there for you is that to preserve style, you need to modify the content of your YAML file on a lower level so that Python doesn't forget the original style. I have shown how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360813/347964). Using the functions defined there, you can reach your desired output like this:

```py
append_to_yaml("input.yaml", "output.yaml", [
  AppendableEvents(["nlu"],
    [MappingStartEvent(None, None, True), key("intent"), key("name"),
     key("examples"), literal_value("- hello there\n- general Kenobi\n"),
     MappingEndEvent()])])
```

This will transform your YAML input into

```yaml
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hey
    - hello
    - hi
    - hello there
- intent: name
  examples: |
    - hello there
    - general Kenobi
```