# How do you insert string quotes when writing key,values to a YAML file with Python?

Tags: python, yaml

I am attempting to update a YAML file where I have a series of key, value pairs that look like

```yaml
key:
   'A': 'B'
   'C': 'D'
```

I clear the file with `f.truncate(0)` and then dump a dictionary back but when dumping the dictionary the key,values don't have the string quotes between key-value pairs. How would I get the dump back to the file to render string quotes?

edit: adding code

```py
with open(filepath, "r+") as f:
    d = yaml.unsafe_load(f)

    # edit dictionary

    # clear file

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0)

    yaml.dump(d, f, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: Please show your existing code.

Comment: You don't need the quote (usually). As long as you're producing correct, equivalent YAML the formatting shouldn't matter. See the accepted answer to this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml

Comment: thank you @Woodford ! that's awesome to know. I will check it out;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the original style by avoiding to load the YAML content into native Python objects:

```py
import yaml,sys

input = """
key:
   'A': 'B'
   'C': 'D'
"""

events = yaml.parse(input)
yaml.emit(events, sys.stdout)

print("---")

node = yaml.compose(input)
yaml.serialize(node, sys.stdout)
```

This code demonstrates using the event API (`parse`/`emit`) to load and dump YAML events, and the node API (`compose`/`serialize`) to load and dump YAML nodes. The output is

```yaml
key:
  'A': 'B'
  'C': 'D'
---
key:
  'A': 'B'
  'C': 'D'
```

As you can see, the scalar style is preserved both times. Of course this is inconvenient if you want to edit the content, you will need to walk the event/node structure to do that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360813/347964) shows how to implement a simple API to append stuff to your YAML using the event API.

For more information about why and when style information is lost when loading YAML into native structures, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964).